# server fault and super user rate limit bonus?

Tags: bug, status-completed

Looks like SF and SU are granting Int.MaxValue rate limit. Not that I mind, but it would be nice to have on the other sites too. ;-)

Thought you would like to know.

```
GET /1.0/users/173?key=mykey HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Soapi.CS 1.0
Accept-Encoding: gzip,gzip
Host: api.serverfault.com


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 05 Aug 2010 20:42:45 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: private
Content-Encoding: gzip
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 2.0
X-RateLimit-Max: 2147483647
X-RateLimit-Current: 2147483485
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Content-Length: 853
```

Comment: good catch +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load balancing confused some code there, should be fixed now.